# Can we use Azure CLI to upload files to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-cli

All I want to do, is to upload files from on prime to Azure Data Lake Storage **Gen2** using the Azure CLI (via ` command), but have a connection error!
Can I use Azure CLI to to that? Or I have to use another tool?
PS: I cannot use Azure Data Factory, I want my job running from my on prime and not from the cloud!
Thks.

```
azure.datalake.store.exceptions.DatalakeRESTException:  HTTP error: 
ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storageAccount.azuredatalakestore.net', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/my-file-system/data.csv?OP=GETFILESTATUS&api-version=2018-05-01 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc7ed169c50>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Azure CLI for gen2 filesystem is not available, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-upgrade?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#programming-interfaces).

[image]

If you want to upload file, here are two workarounds for you to refer.

1. Use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/)
2. Use [AzCopy v10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10), note only v10 supports Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 APIs. Use `myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net` as a URI to call the ADLS Gen2 APIs.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer,
I still have error while copying my files to my Data Lake Storage Gen2 using the AZCopy V10, bellow the command i use, and the error i got:
`azcopy copy "path\to\folder\*" "https://myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/my-container/" --overwrite=false --follow-symlinks --recursive --fromTo=LocalBlobFS`
Error : 
`403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission`

Comment: In the documentation, i found that i can use the SAS Token, but when doing so, got another error : `400 Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header`

Comment: The command i am using : 
`azcopy copy "path\to\folder\*" "https://myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/my-container?SAS-TOKEN" --overwrite=false --follow-symlinks --recursive --fromTo=LocalBlobFS`

Comment: Once I added my user to Storage Blob Contributor, it worked fine.  Wait a few minutes and re-login.

Answer (score 1):

Got it work ^^
So the problem was with my authentication method, to make it work, you have to add your user as a Data Lake Storage Contributor + Owner.
For anyone looking for the Role in the UI it's called "Storage Blob Data Contributor (Preview)". For a Resource Group choose **Access Control (IAM) | Add** in the blade locate the role **Storage Blob Data Contributor (Preview)** and assign access to the Users, Groups or Roles as meets your needs.

Comment: You used AzCopy? If so, I think you could accept my reply as the answer, because it is my solution.